# Terminal does not allow me to provide any input

Tags: macos, terminal

**Specifications:** running OS X Version 10.9.4 on a mac.

**Problem:** 
upon opening either terminal (or iTerminal) I get the following message:

```
Last login: Wed Aug 27 07:45:03 on ttys000
login: /usr/local/bin/bash: No such file or directory

[Process completed]
```

I tried reinstalling my OS X last night, but I still have the same problem today. Any suggestions on what the problem might be? and what I can do to fix it?

**[Edit]** PS: does anyone know what the "ttys000" in the "Last login" row means? I do not recall seeing this before, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: Try to change a terminal shell like this: http://support.apple.com/kb/TA27005 . Can you NOW open a terminal?

Comment: Thanks for the link duDE--that worked!  I basically did the following: terminal --> Preferences --> shell open with --> changed this to /bin/bash from the default. Now I can actually write in the terminal. Not sure how the problem may have occurred though. Also, does anyone have an idea about what "ttys000" in the "last login" row means?

Comment: I would write your solution as an answer and accepted it for the sake of other who has the same problem. Do it please, it's OK to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue I found the following link provided by @duDE helpful: [support.apple.com/kb/TA27005](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA27005)

**In short, do the following:**

1. open your terminal. If it crashes/turns itself off, making it impossible to see the screen try the following:

   terminal --> prefereces --> settings --> shell --> choose "don't close the window" under WHEN THE SHELL EXITS.
2. if you can see the output--something like that in the question that I posted--then do the following:

   preferences --> startup --> SHELL OPENS WITH: choose "Command (complete path)" and enter one of the recommended paths in the link above. The path that worked for me was: /bin/bash

**PS:** My OS and computer specifications are: OS X Version 10.9.4 on a mac.